# Doctrine DQL JOIN

Tags: php, join, orm, doctrine-orm, dql

I have the following entities mapped with [Doctrine 2](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/2.1/docs/hu):

```
class Zone
{
    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Zone", inversedBy="children")
     * @var Zone
     */
    protected $parent;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Zone", mappedBy="parent")
     * @var Zone[]
     */
    protected $children;

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Zone")
     * @var Zone[]
     */
    protected $descendants;
}

class Restaurant
{
    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Zone")
     * @var Zone
     */
    protected $zone;
}
```

Basically, a Zone has a parent, and therefore children. Because children may have children themselves, each Zone keeps a list of all its descendants as well.

Each Restaurant is assigned a Zone.

What I want to do, is to perform a DQL JOIN to return all Restaurants in a specific Zone (including all of its descendants).

If I had to do this in plain SQL, I would write:

```
SELECT r.* from Zone z
JOIN ZoneDescendant d ON d.zoneId = z.id
JOIN Restaurant r ON r.zoneId = d.descendantId
WHERE z.id = ?;
```

Is it possible to do this with Doctrine DQL, without adding a `$restaurants` property on the Zone, and having to complexify the domain model uselessly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, I finally found a way to do it with JOINs only (significantly faster on MySQL):

```
SELECT r
FROM Restaurant r,
     Zone z
JOIN z.descendants d
WHERE r.zone = d
AND z = ?1;
```

Comment: Yeah, thats so much better, glad you found a better soluction! Good idea :)

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of doing this in a single DQL query is to use a subquery:

```
SELECT r FROM Restaurant r WHERE r.zone IN (SELECT zc.id FROM r.zone z JOIN z.children zc WHERE z.id = :zoneId) OR r.zone = :zoneId
```

Comment: This idea works, thanks! However, I have a few concerns about performance. I'm running MySQL 5.6.3 m6, which still does not rewrite these subqueries as JOINs, and slows down drastically when faced to these queries. I think the most efficient solution may be to create a `ZoneRestaurants` view doing the appropriate JOIN, then include a "fake" (unused in the class) `$restaurants` property in the Zone, and map this property as `@ManyToMany` using the ZoneRestaurants view as the junction table.